# RTSP stream in android with username and password

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, rtsp, ip-camera

My task is to create an android application in android to check some IP cameras of the city. Using the existing **RTSP** url which is **rtsp://admin:pms7112@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0** I can get the stream in VLC player but no luck in android. I have tried videoview native player and `media player`. 
Almost every solution gave me

> MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://...

Should this problem happen because the username and password is in the `string`? how could you add the username and password as query `string`?

**EDIT**
Mediaplayer version 
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

```
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("rtsp://admin:pms7112@iphere:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0");
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Update:**
So...it seems that this is the only way I could use the url...I cannot authenticate the user other way. The conpany which owns the camera and setted up for the city do not let us to use other formats. They said, vlc browser addon plays just fine and they will not change anything... So is there any library that implements the rtsp stream with authentication. I heard about a handshake that is made between the client and the server

Comment: Post the code for setDataSource()?

Comment: Are you sure your stream is playable? Have you tested it in VLC for example?

Comment: Yes, VLC plays just fine

Comment: I am concerned about how the url is structured. Is there other way you could send username and password?

Comment: @Coder you are using this format rtsp://[username[:password]@]ip_address[:rtsp_port]/server_URL[?param1=val1[&param2=val2]...[&paramN=valN]]

Comment: @Coder Did you check the above? Yes there is another way to send the username and password?

Comment: I checked it and it's ok. What is the other way?

Comment: similar issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270610/can-i-use-basic-http-authentication-with-android-mediaplayer/29128037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have found [this](https://github.com/vkdinventor/MyVlcPlayer) project o github that uses vlc library to open rtsp streams.This solved my problem solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Format is `rtsp://[username[:password]@]ip_address[:rtsp_port]/server_U‌​RL[?param1=val1[&par‌​am2=val2]...[&paramN‌​=valN]]`

Another way to send the username and password:

```
Uri source = Uri.parse("rtsp://iphere:554/cam/realmonitor");
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("SERVER_KEY_TO_PARSE_USER_NAME", "admin");
headers.put("SERVER_KEY_TO_PARSE_PASSWORD", "pms7112");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers)
```

Just a suggestion and optional try to call `mediaplayer.prepareAsync()` and not `mediaplayer.prepare()`

> In order to access media presentations from RTSP servers that require
> authentication, the client MUST additionally be able to do the
> following:
> * recognize the 401 status code;
> * parse and include the WWW-Authenticate header;
> * implement Basic Authentication and Digest Authentication.

**Reference** [Authentication-enabled](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-86)

Comment: @Coder did you check the above?

Comment: Right now I don't have access to the server to check the server keys, but I tested with "admin" and "password" and did not worked. I logged the vlc requests and I got the Authentication header. Is that enough to authenticate?

Comment: @Coder Yes, but in that case what is the authentication headers you received from vlc?

Comment: Sending request: PLAY rtsp://iphere:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype
=0 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 9
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cG1zNzExMg==
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)
Session: 295295060303
Range: npt=0.000-

Comment: @Coder Till the time you don't have access to server. try to add only in the header headers.put("Authorization:", "Basic YWRtaW46cG1zNzExMg==");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137136/discussion-between-anurag-singh-and-coder).

Comment: So...it seems that this is the only way I could use the url...I cannot authenticate the user other way. The conpany which owns the camera and setted up for the city do not let us to use other formats. They said, vlc browser addon plays just fine and they will not change anything... So is there any library that implements the rtsp stream with authentication. I heard about a handshake that is made between the client and the server

Comment: I will let you know by tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using this library, its limited to 2 mins of playback but for my purposes that was not a problem.

https://github.com/VideoExpertsGroup/MediaPlayerSDK

I have tested multiple android libs and this one seems to work the best in android. Some other ones I have tested were choppy with playback or very delayed. There is also a test app so you can confirm it will work with your stream.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rtspplr.app

Comment: It's limited to 2 mins? What?