# streaming audio with authentication

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I am trying to play a stream audio from ip camera with native Android.

My url is something similar to `http://url.of.camera:port/dgaudio.cgi`
I have basic authentication with username and password.
I am using android MediaPlayer to play the stream.

I've tried the approch posted here [Can I use Basic HTTP Authentication with Android MediaPlayer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128037)

but it is not working.
Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So far no one seems found a solution so here my suggestion. 
It is **NOT** a real solution but a workaround that may help people who wants to test streaming audio from IP Camera or similar.

- Create a webview in your layout (make it invisible, we want just to play audio, but if you want to see the player as it would be in a web browser you can make the webview visible) and a button to play/stop audio

> ```
> <WebView
>     android:id="@+id/web_view_audio"
>     android:visibility="invisible"
>     android:layout_width="1dp"
>     android:layout_height="1dp"/>
>
> <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btn_audio"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="play"
>         />
> ```

in you activity when click on the play button load into the webview the url http://USER:PASS@url.of.camera:port/dgaudio.cgi, and when click on stop load empty html code

> ```
> private void playAudio() {
>         if(playAudio) {
>             webView.loadUrl(urlAudio);
>
>             btnAudio.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btn_audio_stop));
>
>         }else {
>
>             btnAudio.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btn_audio_play));
>
>             String customHtml = "<html><body></body></html>";
>             webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
>         }
>     }
> ```